# C# client for QT server

Tags: c#, qt, sockets

need help.
There is a QT socket. I need to write a client in C#.

An example of a working client on QT. But I need to do it in C#.

```
 QTcpSocket& operator<< (QTcpSocket& socket,QMASMsgLoginReuired& msg)
{
    QByteArray array;
    QDataStream out(&array,QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    out.setVersion(QDataStream::Qt_5_2);
    out << quint32(0) << quint8(0);
    out << message.ToString();
    out.device()->seek(0);
    out << quint32(array.size()-sizeof(quint32));
    socket.write(array);
    socket.flush();
    socket.waitForBytesWritten();
    return socket;
}
```

It is my code in C#, but not work

```
String response = String.Empty;
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("192.168.1.1", 5550);
Console.WriteLine(message);
NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
writer.AutoFlush = false;
writer.Write("0");
writer.Write(message);
writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message).Length);
writer.Flush();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
response = reader.ReadLine();
stream.Close();
```

Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Please describe what specifically [doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).

Comment: i don't get any response, apparently the server can't deserialize my command

Comment: `ReadLine` will just be one line, is that what you want? You are also missing `using` blocks.

Comment: In response I should get xml